# Posting a table via hidden input runs into varchar2 and htp.p size limit

Tags: oracle

I have tables which can be sorted and filtered on the browser side, via jquery plugins. There is also a download button which copies the modified content of the table to a hidden input and submits it to oracle which then prints the value of the input using htp.p with a excel header. This works fine for tables of a certain size, I am prompted to open the file in excel.

On larger tables though I get this. 
mod_plsql: /pls/braganza/play.download_filtered HTTP-400 Value param too long. Length is 53169. Upper limit is 32512

Any ways of circumventing this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically buffer your input field across multiple fields. Pseudo code:

- Assign Table to Hidden Input
- IF

  - [Hidden Input].length < 32k
  - Submit
- ELSE

  - Hidden Input #1 = [Hidden Input].Substring(1, 32k)
  - Hidden Input #2 = [Hidden Input].Substring(32k+1, 64k)
  - Hidden Input #3 = [Hidden Input].Substring(64k+1, 96k)
  - Submit

This is the same/similar method used for large (32k+) clob fields in APEX.

I would also switch to the flexible parameter passing nature of mod_plsql access. It will save you tons of time/hassle for this particular problem if you are not already using it on this.

Comment: A link on Flexible Parameter Passing: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12303/concept.htm#1005765